# display image in my page using echo

Tags: php, image, get

this is code of the page that I will get the image from(work perfectly)

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    include('connect.php');

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id=$id");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    echo $row['image'];
?>
```

and this is my page that i get the image to in

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    include('includes/connect.php');
    include('includes/phpCodes.php');

    $id = $_GET['id'];

    function showNews() {
        $data = array( 'id' => $id );
        $base = "includes/getImage.php";
        $url = $base. "?" . "id=36";
        echo $url;
        echo '<img src=includes/getImage.php class="newsImage">';
        echo '<h1><p class="subjecTitle">هنا العنوان</p></h1>   
                 <div class="newsContent">
                    hihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihi
             </div>
        ';
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>عينٌ على الحقيقة</title>

        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mainstyle.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/showstyle.css">
        <script lang="javascript">
            function logout( myFrame ) {
                myFram.submit();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <?php headerCode(); ?>
            <div class="content" dir="rtl">
                <?php showNews(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

i think my wrong is in , can someone tell me how can I solve it?, sorry for my bad english

Comment: @BassamBadr now see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17940111/display-image-in-my-page-using-echo/17940260#17940260

Comment: Check the image path. Just confirm, image is there or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleared it up for you:

```
echo '<img src="includes/getImage.php?id=' . $id . '" class="newsImage">';
```

Should 100% work (if the $id param has a value of course).

Update to fix the missing $id var:

```
    <?php
        ob_start();
        session_start();
        include('includes/connect.php');
        include('includes/phpCodes.php');

        $id = $_GET['id'];

        function showNews(){
            $id = $_GET['id'];
            $base = "includes/getImage.php";
            $url = $base. "?" . "id=36";
            echo $url;
            echo '<img src="includes/getImage.php?id=' . $id . '" class="newsImage">';

            echo '
                <h1><p class="subjecTitle">??? ???????</p></h1> 
                <div class="newsContent"></div>
            ';
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '>' in C:\AppServ\www\Eye\show.php on line 15

Comment: Are you positive your source looks exactly the same as provided by me? This will work and will not generate an error. Please show me your code as it looks like now.

Comment: See this working example: http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/2h3-7ck and press 'run' to the right. Will result in a img tag without parsing errors. Are you sure you have exactly the same string on line 15?

Comment: it works but the image didn't display

Comment: the sourc look like this <img src="includes/getImage.php?id=" class="newsImage">

Comment: The $id var was empty in that case and I see why (see my updated code)

Comment: I would like to add that the code is not safe for exploits (using unescaped $_GET data) see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695973/php5-security-get-post-parameters

Comment: after 10 hours of work :) Now it's work im so so so happy, thank you so much brother

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
echo ' <img src=includes/getImage.php class="newsImage">';
```

To :

```
echo ' <img src="includes/getImage.php?id='.$id.'" class="newsImage">';
```

Please note `src` has `"` and also make sure that `includes/getImage.php` return a image path

Comment: I want to sent id as parameter to getImage.php

Comment: Just send it like this : `includes/getImage.php?id=1` in `getImage.php` use `$_GET['id']` to get this id

Comment: convert it to <img src="includes/getImage.php?id=$id" class="newsImage"> ; still get nothing

Comment: check in firebug or view souce and see what is the value for `src` in source

Comment: the source is <img src="includes/getImage.php?id=$id" class="newsImage"> ;

Comment: @BassamBadr try my code.

Comment: If you execute the  `includes/getImage.php?id=1` from browser are you getting the path of the image ?

Comment: @Prasanth Bendra im using google chrome when i open a show.php I pressed f12 and the copy the source <img src="includes/getImage.php?id=$id" class="newsImage">

Comment: @BassamBadr see my comment because the $id param is not parsed by PHP in your current setup

Answer (score 0):

why are you using two different pages?
put both code in single page and simply do this

```
 <img src=includes/<?php echo $row['image']; ?> class="newsImage">
```